# How to fix unlimited vertical scrolling issue of fixed column in html

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I implemented fixed column table in my asp.net mvc project. It is okay with horizontal scrolling. But when I hover on fixed column, the column gets unlimited vertical scrolling and sometimes shakes screen continuously.
This is the simple razor view(NewTable.cshtml):

```
<style>
    table {
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        *margin-left: -100px; /*ie7*/
    }

    td, th {
        vertical-align: top;
        border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 100px;
    }

    .fix {
        position: absolute;
        *position: relative;
        margin-left: -100px;
        width: 100px;
    }

    .outer {
        position: relative;
    }

    .inner {
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: visible;
        width: 400px;
        margin-left: 100px;
    }
</style>
<h2>This is fixed column demo</h2>
<div class="inner">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="fix">Header 1</th>
                <th>Header 2</th>
                <th>Header 3</th>
                <th>Header 4</th>
                <th>Header 5</th>
                <th>Header 5</th>
                <th>Header 5</th>
                <th>Header 5</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="fix">data 1</td>
                <td>data 2</td>
                <td>data 3</td>
                <td>data 4</td>
                <td>data 5</td>
                <td>data 5</td>
                <td>data 5</td>
                <td>data 5</td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And this is the screen when I hover my mouse on the first fixed column:
[image]

N:B: when I set my layout=null, then this works absolutely fine. If you have any particular hint/solution then please let me know to solve this unlimited vertical scrolling issue. So the problem was related to layout I was using. Anyway I got rid of the problem adding the css in the answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the fixed column's unlimited vertical scroll by setting the style of the fixed columns like this: `style="overflow-y: hidden;"`